# Publishing Android App Update for certain users only

Tags: android, google-play, developer-console

Is it possible publish an android app update to users of some custom defined segments only? I know you can for instance remove the support for a specific version of Android and then the update will not be visible to the android users running that specific version. But can you define a segment of users and then drop the update support for that specific segment?

thank

Comment: No you can’t, but if you publish app as closed beta and keep it in beta status then you can add or remove emails of users who will get the app no other users will be allowed

Comment: No, but you could potentially achieve what you want with Firebase. Search for "RemoteConfig" and "Audiences" - together, you could define a set of users as an "audience" and then toggle the change with remote config for that audience.

Comment: Firebase is not an option because of the Chinese Great WAll. But the beta approach is interesting. Thank you guys!